# NTFS recovery software for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, ntfs, data-recovery

I need a free Linux application to recover some files on an NTFS partition.
Please suggest a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Testdisk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk]

which includes Photorec can do this. See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30791/all-files-erased-after-installing-ubuntu-11-04-alpha-3/31066#31066).

Answer (score 1):

check this answer

[Tool for recovering deleted data from a flash drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31450/tool-for-recovering-deleted-data-from-a-flash-drive/31453#31453)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recover files which have been deleted and not overwritten then go for [ntfsundelete](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery/NtfsUndelete). This has helped me in the past to recover my accidentally deleted files.