# Full internal harddrive converted to ext4 file system, how to install Windows back again?

Tags: ntfs, gparted, ext4, disk-management

I had Windows 7 installed on my laptop, with hard drive partitioned. I installed Ubuntu formatting the drive as it didn't detect I had Windows 7 too already. It installed correctly, but now when I'm also trying to install Windows I don't have a drive of NTFS file system as it converted to ext4 completely (all 500 GB WD). Please help me in installing Windows too.

Comment: you can try to recover your files, see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49497/ntfs-recovery-software-for-ubuntu), but if you installed linux over windows, it's likely that your data is gone for good.

Comment: To reinstall windows you'll need to create an NTFS partition (either the whole drive or just a part of it) and install windows onto that.

Comment: its not the data i m worried about..just need to get the windows working again along with ubuntu..

Comment: creating an NTFS partition is precisely what i m looking for..how to get it done...plz guide me

Answer (score 0):

Boot from your installation media (live USB or live DVD). Run `gparted` and reduce the size of the Ubuntu partition. Add another partition and format it to NTFS).

Install Windows.

At this point, Windows will load but not Ubuntu, because Windows removes Grub the Ubuntu boot loader.

So again boot from your live USB or DVD and repair grub.

Install and run `boot-repair` and choose "recommended repair".

Source site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: in gparted when i right click on my internal hard drive all the options exceptunmount,manage flags and information are all faded...gparted feels useless at the moment..plz tell me step by step instructions..will b very grateful..:)

Comment: Click Unmount, then the other options should become available.

Comment: installed windows first using mini xp..problem solved..thanksss

Comment: It might help others if you explain what you actually did in more detail.