# Help with Data Recovery from a Windows Faliure

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

My SSD holding Windows crashed and I am currently stuck trying to recover the data from my 750GB HDD. I am using GParted to do this, and the drive with all my important data on it is not mounting. Here's a screenshot of the screen and error:

[image]

I'm no expert, but it looks to me like I might have a major problem with this data recovery. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ntfs recovery software for ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49497/ntfs-recovery-software-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

1. install `ntfs-3g` if that is not already on your system
2. try again `gparted`
3. if it fails again with the same error: get yourself a windows rescue boot CD
   one of these will do: http://www.pcc-services.com/windows/guide-noboot2.html
4. boot with it and follow the instructions
5. if that is done, boot windows and run `chkdsk /f`
6. reboot **two** times

Comment: So, basically what the error says :). Lol, thanks for the fast reply, I'll get on that when I get home.

Comment: yes :-) I thought you might like this guided tour but if you want to go another route you can do this instead: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/   but I doubt it will work in your case

Comment: Yeah, btw, I basically lost my windows file in the crash, although I have a backup from Friday, I can't boot from it as it is on an external drive. Point is, will the rescue boot allow me to access the files?

Comment: So it is NOT your windows boot device ? Well, at least you can forget about point 4, 5 and 6 then ;-) Nevertheless, it will fix your filesystem if that is physically possible, and regarding the info you shared I have good hope :-)

Comment: No, the computer itself was my windows machine, but not anymore. This event is the push towards Linux for me. After I get my data, I am going to install either Ubuntu or Mint. I work part time in the web design field, so I'm gonna just run a copy of windows 7 with dream weaver from a virtual box.

Comment: dream weaver runs perfectly under "wine" (a compatibility layer, not an emulator or VM) there is even a preset for dream weaver in "winetricks". You don't even need a virtualbox :-)

Comment: So, a little more clarification if possible. By SSD crash, I mean that I no longer have a working copy of windows, so will chkdsk /f work on the windows recovery cd command line?

Comment: Quite possibly yes

Answer (score 0):

What gparted is trying to communicate is that the boot parameter block and volume boot record were corrupted and illegible\unreadable.  Like a corrupt file header.  In that block is the pointer to the $MFT (Master File Table) similar to Superblock in Linux.  Somehow the partition got shifted leading to the offset and loss of magic number.    Good news is that there is a backup of the bpb\vbr at the end of the ntfs partition ... Total number of sectors -1 there could be an issue as to whether it is at the end of user data or formatted space.  Nevertheless it is there and has the location of your $MFT which will get you your data back.    So invoke gnu ddrescue and run it in reverse to image the backup boot sector.  Then image the whole drive extract $MFT and use Johann Schnicht's "RawCopy" to do a low level extraction of data from Master File Table.