# How do I recover the pictures and videos I lost when I erased the disk and installed Ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I had four NTFS partitions on my drive. One on which Windows 7 was installed (C Drive) and others contained my data (D Drive) (E Drive) (F drive).

During Ubuntu installation I chose to install Ubuntu and erase my existing OS. When Ubuntu was installed, I was shocked to see no partitions. All my data was gone. I must have done something wrong in selecting my option during installation.

I tried testdisk in my other PC with the hard drive. I messed up with the thing I deleted the Ubuntu and made a single partition.

Is there any way I can recover my D Drive? I don't care about the other partitions - I just need my pictures and videos which I captured. I have almost all computer equipment so just name it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You apparently installed Ubuntu on the whole harddrive, therefore deleting all the partitons that were there previously. If you have all the equipment, just repartition the drive and copy the pictures from your backup harddrive.

Comment: Well, [Testdisk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30791/all-files-erased-after-installing-ubuntu-11-04-alpha-3) is the way to go. Why did it fail? See also [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94421/is-there-a-way-to-recover-files-from-a-storage-device-partially-overwritten-with) and many other questions.

Answer (score 1):

TestDisk can recover partitions. Use that. If partition is unreadable that is is beyond recover then you can do nothing. Data recovery depends on how much you overwritten the data.

In any case, I'm sure Ubuntu have written (overwritten?) small part of the disk so I believe you can recover some. I'm sure you messed somewhere in using testdisk. May be you tried to recover **data** instead of **partitions**. Checkout [this guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Partition_table_recovery) on how to do that! Here is [another link](http://geexhq.com/recover-partition-table/) to help on the same using live CD
All the best!