# Lost my files? I've installed Ubuntu wrong

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery

I wanted to do a dual boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNCSbTyUzoM

When I was on the installing Ubuntu part, the free space was not showing, it was showing as unusable. So I clicked on my C drive on the installation screen and pressed the - button to remove the partition I created and just created the swap space on the C drive and installed Ubuntu on the C drive choosing to use 50GB. So I installed, rebooted and can no longer run Windows 8, where all my files are accessible.

I'm not just talking movies, tv shows galore that I have not watched. I'm talking about all the music I've collected over 3 years and all my pictures and important documents. I know I should have a backup, but I don't so that's that.

Now, can I do anything to access these files at all on Ubuntu, because I cannot find this 'host' folder containing my Windows 8 user where all my files are.

Thanks for your time, I hope I ain't buggered this up!

Comment: No, Windows 8 fast boot has caused some files to be lost when dual booting with Linux distros, including Ubuntu.

Comment: Not understanding what this means. I just want access to my files, I care none for Windows 8... just my files.

Comment: You may be able to recover most your data with [data recovery tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30791/all-files-erased-after-installing-ubuntu-11-04-alpha-3) but before all **stop using the drive**.

Comment: @hugo read this, you will understand better. http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html

Comment: @Takkat , The existing problem relating to windows 8 MUST be solved. It might not be the drive problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file explorer in Ubuntu and on the left side, under "devices" it will say something like "50gb file system" (it may not be 50gb it will be whatever you set it to)

That file system is your windows 8 partition.  Once there, you can browse it just like in windows; it contains the same files.

When you start up your computer what does it look like? Do you get a menu that lets you choose between Ubuntu and Windows? If these don't work you may have done the installation wrong and deleted your entire windows partition.

Thirdly, the Ubuntu install comes with a partitioning tool (`gparted` or `fdisk`), you didn't have to make it in Windows. Instead when it says "install alongside windows 8" just choose that option and press "install".

Comment: What is the file explorer you're talking about? I can't see anything related to a 50GB file system of any sorts. 

When I boot my laptop, I get the choice of Ubuntu and Windows 8 but Windows will show a blue screen with an error and then I cannot continue.

Comment: choose ubuntu the file explorer in there is on the left hand side... its the orange folder icon

Comment: and it doesn't have to be a 50 GB file system... it will be the size of whatever your windows partition is

Comment: No, cannot find anything. Remote desktop is possible here right? Anyone want to see if they can access my files?

Comment: I've never used remote desktop but if you want to try it then set it up.

Comment: What remote desktop app/software should I use Dave?

Comment: in Ubuntu on the left top corner click the dash icon.  open it and type desktop sharing select that and choose allow other to view your desktop and allow others to control your desktop ... it may not work though it may not allow connection from outside your local connection.

Comment: I'm not to familiar with this so I can't promise you anything.

Comment: Yes I think that is only for others near you. Any other suggestions?

Comment: sorry I don't...  if you can't access your windows 8 partition in Ubuntu then I am afraid you may not be able to get it back at all.

Comment: There is no possible way to access my HDD beyond these this 50GB disk space? I'd even be willing to pay for it.

Comment: I don't know of any.